How can I extract vector data from a web map service raster layer
How can I interact with a raster layer from an ArcGIS REST Map Service for spatial analysis purposes, given the service's limitations on data manipulation and querying, particularly when direct downloading or raster-to-feature conversion isn't supported?
This is the URL for the map service. I'm trying to do this either in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro and am also willing to look into Python options.
https://www.sciencebase.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Catalog/56ba0f9ce4b08d617f648f47/MapServer/17

The purpose of this is to perform a spatial join and see where some of my polygon feature classes will land when overlapped with the WMS

This won't answer your question but hopefully give you some pointers on how to start tackling this problem.
Try reading up on the ArcGIS Rest API documentation on how to work with this resource. Unfortunately there is no working metadata, help site or other resource working on the link you provide. Hence I am not sure if everything will work as described in the API.
An alternative approach could be to try and export the data somehow, a start can be either

Load it into QGIS, use Layer > Add Layer > Add ArcGIS Rest Server > New and then enter https://www.sciencebase.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Catalog/56ba0f9ce4b08d617f648f47/MapServer/ as the URL. Press Connect, open Services and you will see the Depth to water layer which you can Add to QGIS. From here you can try to play around with the export options to save a .tif file but I could only get it working with the displayed RGB value as separate bands instead of the underlying data. Here is a similar thread
Export it via the API, in your browser enter https://www.sciencebase.gov/arcgis/rest/services/Catalog/56ba0f9ce4b08d617f648f47/MapServer/export?bbox=931506.274797037,211463.34823461308,1606044.5359519299,450152.8431086063&format=tif&imageSR=2263&layers=show:17, important are the bounding box and crs as well as specifying the layer used. You will need to add other options to it as described in the API to get the right aspect ratio/scale/image size, but this should serve as a decent starting point of what you can export and how. A similar problem is described here
Python approach on working with the API could also help, especially if with your initial request of querying the data directly

